# How can I get "complex JSON" from a kafka topic and insert it in several tables in MySQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I'm a Kafka beginner so it is possible there is an API or a tool that could help me, but I do not know it. If I'm approaching this problem wrongly and you leave me know it, I would really appreciate it.

I have a JSON in my topic which looks something like this:

```
{
  "id": "001",
  "value": "30000",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "chicken breast",
      "value": "2300"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "Cookies",
      "value": "2400"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I need to take and insert it in a database similar to:

[image: Database structure]

should I create a KafkaStreamApp, transform my data trying to simplify that JSON? or is any way to "map" or construct each row that I need to insert in each table with a KafkaConnect?

P.S: This is a simplified JSON example, the JSON in my topic will be much more complex.

Comment: If it was me, I'd write an application using an idempotent consumer and use JDBC to insert/upsert the records into the database.

Comment: @thsutton could you give me more details, and maybe explain to me why you would do it this way?

Comment: You have a JSON document containing records that need to go in several tables with foreign key constraints. So a single SQL transaction that inserts the bill and the items in one go seems like a sensible idea. Splitting into multiple topics (one for bills, for items, etc) makes it hard to maintain relational integrity in the database.

Comment: If you have additional requirements like "the schema changes every week" or "we have to do 1000 slightly different versions of this" then the answer would probably be different.

Comment: Kafka doesn't really lend itself well in the relational world. Is there a limitation that you cannot use a document database? Otherwise, you'll definitely want a Kafka Streams topology that at the very least, has flatMap to get individual rows, but that would just get you to a Bill and Item table. You'd need a KStream join to generate a BillDetail record

Comment: @ONECRICKETEER This is a simplified example, in the real implementation I will take a JSON and I could need to Insert its data in 10 or 12 tables at BigQuery ... Would you say the best way to approach this is with a KafkaStreamApp instead of a KafkaConnect? or What do you think is the best way to do this?  I would really appreciate any suggest

Comment: There's a connector for BigQuery, but your question said mysql... In any case, connect and streams are commonly used together to built robust pipelines, but for joins on foreign keys specifically, you'd need streams